# jquery script issue while using third party pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, pagination

I am implementing twbs pagination but it needs the script of

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

but my existing code needs the script

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

if i add both the script my pagination is not working..

The code is

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
        <ul id="pagination-demo" class="pagination-sm"></ul>
      </div>
<div id="page-content" class="page-content">Page 1</div>
```

Do any know any solution to add both the script and all working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those in reality are the same code. One is just minified and not easily human readable. Either one should work but not both.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Comment: in my code <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> is not working for  twbs pagination implementation...

Comment: Just include the .min one but only that one. You cant include multiple jqueries on the same page.

Comment: Thanks a lot will do that

Answer (score 1):

Why your existing code is not working on the minified one? Just use the .min.js (compressed version of jQuery) file and it should be ok. Never include jQuery twice.

Comment: So do you want to say that the code should work on minified one and if it is not working then use .min.js(compressed)..

Comment: Only use this one:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>